# Join does not work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have write a function using SQL join but i do not know why it does not work

this is a model

```
public function get_contract_user($user_id) 
{
    $this->db->select('contracts.*');
    $this->db->from('contracts');       
    $this->db->join('link', 'contracts.contract_id = link.contracts_contract_id');
    $this->db->where('link.users_user_id', $user_id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();  
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

this is the app

```
$data['query'] = $this->admin_model->get_contract_user($contract_id);
```

this is a view

```
foreach($query as $row) 
{       
    echo $row->contract_code; 
    echo $row->contract_num;
    echo $row->contract_start;
    echo $row->contract_end;
}
```

Comment: what "doesn't work" about it, do you get errors? is the data wrong? you need to be more specific than that.

Comment: $this->db->last_query() use this function to see what is produced and test it in phpmyadmin

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I do not get anything in codeigniter but  when i use  $query  = " SELECT `contracts`.* FROM `contracts` 
   JOIN `link` ON `contracts`.`contract_id` = `link`.`contracts_contract_id` 
   WHERE `link`.`users_user_id` =  '$id' "; in plain php i get output

Comment: The CI output would be the same as your query. But you are using `$id` on your query, not `$user_id`. Also, on your controller, it seems that you are passing `$contract_id` and matching it against `$user_id` ??

Comment: i have also face this problem in ci many times bt i dont know y it comes so i just use plain php sql formatting in my model to solve my problem and i advice u that u also try with it.

Answer (score 3):

You defined method `get_contract_user`, but you are using `get_contract` in provided code.

You should be getting an error concerning undefined function/method.

Comment: i did change the method name but still got nothing from the query